# How to fix fluent interface with Getters and Setters in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

My IDE settings in PHPStorm says that the template of "PHP Setter Method" is:

```
/**
 * @param ${TYPE_HINT} $${PARAM_NAME}
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public ${STATIC} function set${NAME}($${PARAM_NAME})
{
#if (${STATIC} == "static")
    self::$${FIELD_NAME} = $${PARAM_NAME};
#else
    $this->${FIELD_NAME} = $${PARAM_NAME};
#end


    return $this;
}
```

And the result is:

```
/**
 * @param string $cellularPhonePrefix
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCellularPhonePrefix($cellularPhonePrefix)
{
    $this->cellularPhonePrefix = $cellularPhonePrefix;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCellularPhonePrefix()
{
    return $this->cellularPhonePrefix;
}
```

Someone know the way to leave one empty line between

```
$this->cellularPhonePrefix = $cellularPhonePrefix;
```

and

```
return $this
```

?

Comment: Add it **before** `#end` in actual template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just copied your template and it works with PS-138.567 (PHPStorm 8 EAP).
Be sure to activate "Blank line before return statement" at Code Style->PHP->Other.

Answer (score 2):

static methods returning $this?

```
/**
 * @param ${TYPE_HINT} $${PARAM_NAME}
#if (${STATIC} != "static")
 *
 * @return ${CLASS_NAME}
#end
 */
public ${STATIC} function set${NAME}($${PARAM_NAME})
{
#if (${STATIC} == "static")
    self::$${FIELD_NAME} = $${PARAM_NAME};
#else
    $this->${FIELD_NAME} = $${PARAM_NAME};

    return $this;
#end
}
```

Comment: Now I use vim and I am an happy. I cant verify your response. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried your example. In PhpStorm 7.1 it works with the empty line in the template.

If you have the "Reformat to Style" option set for the template, these lines might get deleted right after insertion.

Your code style needs to allow empty lines.

Another option would be to set "empty line before return statement" in your code style.